# How to recode one column conditional on another

Tags: r, recode

I currently have a dataframe in R with a variable for names ("Name") and one that notes whether an individual is female ("Female") (1, NA). A given individual likely has multiple rows because they responded to the survey multiple times. However, sometimes, the "Female" column is incorrect and will not list an individual who has previously responded to being Female (1), as (1) and instead will have an NA.

So for example, if my dataset looks like this:

```
Name <- c("Claire Smith", "John Doe", "Serena Williams", "Claire Smith", "Claire Smith", "Serena Williams")
Female <- c(1, NA, NA, NA, NA, 1)
df <- data.frame(Name, Female)
```

I want it to check across all rows so that it will recognize that "Claire Smith" and "Serena Williams" do have at least one "1" associated for their "Names" and propagate the rest of the "Female" columns for these names as "1".
So I would want the code to do this:

```
Name <- c("Claire Smith", "John Doe", "Serena Williams", "Claire Smith", "Claire Smith", "Serena Williams")
Female <- c(1, NA, 1, 1, 1, 1)
df <- data.frame(Name, Female)
```

I'm sure this is quite an easy fix but I can't seem to figure it out. Thank you very much in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using a bit of `dplyr` you can use

```
library(dplyr)

df %>% 
  mutate(Female=any(Female==1)+0, .by=Name)
#              Name Female
# 1    Claire Smith      1
# 2        John Doe     NA
# 3 Serena Williams      1
# 4    Claire Smith      1
# 5    Claire Smith      1
# 6 Serena Williams      1
```

You just check for any "1" value for the name and propagate that to the group. The `any()` function returns a TRUE/FALSE value so we use `+0` to turn TRUE into 1.

Comment: This still didn't seem to propagate the "Female" column for the ones that were not already previously propagated. Is there a certain variable type that either variable should be in? Thank you.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand. I ran this on the input you provided and got the result you desired. Is there some other case that I'm missing?

Comment: Sorry, it did work in this example but I have a larger dataset that I drew this example from. However, it seems like I had some weird spacing issues in my original dataset that was affecting the output. Fixing that seemed to sort it all out and your code worked perfectly. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 2):

A base R approach would be to use `tapply` and `match`:

```
xx <- tapply(df$Female, df$Name, sum, na.rm = TRUE)
df$Female2 <- xx[match(df$Name, names(xx))]
```

Output:

```
#              Name Female Female2
# 1    Claire Smith      1       1
# 2        John Doe     NA       0
# 3 Serena Williams     NA       1
# 4    Claire Smith     NA       1
# 5    Claire Smith     NA       1
# 6 Serena Williams      1       1
```

Note I made `Female2` just for demonstration but could overwrite `Female` if desired.

Also, to preserve the `NA` instead of recoding males to 0, could do:

```
xx <- tapply(df$Female, df$Name, function(x) +any(x == 1))
df$Female2 <- xx[match(df$Name, names(xx))]

#              Name Female Female2
# 1    Claire Smith      1       1
# 2        John Doe     NA      NA
# 3 Serena Williams     NA       1
# 4    Claire Smith     NA       1
# 5    Claire Smith     NA       1
# 6 Serena Williams      1       1
```

Answer (score 1):

```
library(tidyverse)
group_by(df, Name)%>%
   fill(Female, .direction = 'updown')

# A tibble: 6 × 2
# Groups:   Name [3]
  Name            Female
  <chr>            <dbl>
1 Claire Smith         1
2 John Doe            NA
3 Serena Williams      1
4 Claire Smith         1
5 Claire Smith         1
6 Serena Williams      1
```